# Is it possible to change/override autogenerated html code of a DRUPAL module?

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-7

I'm using Commerce module for product catalog and for a single product i have fields like: image, title, price, weight,... and i would like to display image on the left side and text fields (title, price,...) right next to it. But the auto-generated code looks something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
         <img></img>
    </div>

    <div>Title</div>
    <div>Price</div>
    <div>Weigth</div>
    <div>Size</div>
</div>
```

So ofcourse, I am able to style the div containing an image with css with

```
width: 50%;
```

But I cant do that with those divs containing text info, since they are by themselves and dont have a wrapper div. So my question is there a way to "manually" add that wrapper div? Or maybe another way to solve this?

Comment: You mean like this - http://jsfiddle.net/krbfb4gv/

Comment: Yeah that helped, although I had to make some more tweaking. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, using a custom templates (in your theme). You can also look at modules like Fences and Display suite to control markups for your node.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own 'Theme' elements.  Instead of doing the changes in your, let's say, Bartik Theme, (Commerce is your module).  Create a new folder with your own theme name inside

```
> sites  
> all  
> themes  
> your-theme-folder
```

Copy the theme you have now and do your changes inside your css file accordingly.

Make your theme your default.